# Auto Load a Link

Tags: html

I have this project that I need a modal box to appear when they login for the first time.

I'm using a class called *superbox* which works well but it's activated by clicking links with **href** and **rel** attributes attached.

So I was wondering if there was a way of auto clicking the link on page load.

This is the link below:

```
<a href="#testbox" rel="superbox[content][470x225]">Open</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay basically, auto clicking literally doesn't exist. But you can activate the box on pageload.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //alert('page was loaded!');
    SomeSuperBoxOpeningFunction('content', '470x225');
});
```

**EDIT**

But since there is no such feature in superbox plugin. Then lets make a totally alternative fix for that:

**http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/8FLkx/**

This is a very very simple idea behind showing some boxes.

Comment: I'd need to include the #testbox as well, any thoughts?

Comment: Well, you didn't mention this. What is #testbox? And what is the purpose of #testbox?

Comment: #testbox is the id of the box that is opened. There are multiple box's on the page. Thanks for you help so far.

Comment: Oh right, right.. Basically yes. However, this superbox plugin doesn't seem to have direct feature for that. Is the #testbox style and everything set? Because, then you could make an alternative fix for that.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the sourcecode of your superbox and found the the following function:

```
function showBox(curSettings, $elt)
```